# Any potential danger using constants in header files of C++ and asking their addresses in the program

Tags: c++, storage, constants, linkage

I am defining constants in a header file and including in source files of my project. The C++ compiler normally does not create storage for these constants and keep their linkage as internal. If I ask for the address of any constant in my program, the compiler will be forced to create a storage for that constant variable. My question is if the compiler is creating storage for a constant variable, will the linkage of the variable also gets affected? Because if the linkage gets external, I would get linking errors while compilation. My test program does not give any linkage error when I point a pointer to a constant of the included header file (which needs the address of the constant). I will be grateful if any one can explain briefly the concepts of storage and linkage in C++ or direct me to some good explanation available somewhere. Thanks in advance.

```
//in constants.h
const double UNIT_LENGTH = 1e-10;
//in constants.cpp
#include "constants.h"
const double * temp = &UNIT_LENGTH;
//in main
#include "constants.h"
double A = UNIT_LENGTH;  //why there is no linking error
```

Comment: Please provide a brief example of what you're describing, as actual code.

Comment: Why do you want to take the address of a constant?  Most processor instructions are more efficient with the value of the constant rather than taking the address, then dereferencing the address.

Answer (score 1):

Const-qualified variables have internal linkage. In the 2012 standard the wording in 3.5/3 is

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of [...]
>
> - a variable that is explicitly declared const or constexpr and neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage

"Namespace scope" includes the global namespace.

Whether you declare them in a header file or not is irrelevant, but be aware that in each translation unit the header file will define a different object. That will usually not matter because it's const, unless you want to compare addresses across translation units.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The linkage of global const variables in C++ (unlike in C) is defined to always be internal (aka static). So the problem you fear will not happen.

It is quite on the contrary. If you were to treat a global constant as you would a normal global variable, you would cause [linker errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/global-constants-in-cpp?view=vs-2017).

(But note that if those are `char *` variables, they need to be `const char * const`, not just `const char *`. Similar for other pointers, but chars are most often used.)